# Excel Novice. Need assistance creating a formula per below:

Tags: excel

I would like help identifying and classifying transactions in an excel sheet.  The transactions are text in 1 sheet and I have another mapping spreadsheet.  The mapping spreadsheet contains a string (sub text) of the transaction spreadsheet and the classification in another column. i.e. Column A text = Mazda & Column B text = Car Lease Payments whereby, column B is the classification.   I want a formula on transaction sheet, whereby any transaction listed with the word Mazda in it would return "Car Lease Payments".  Is there a forumla for this?

Comment: Excel questions should be asked on https://superuser.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for but it is one approach to the problem. If you have multiple classification keywords you can simply add more columns and concatenate them together, then hide the ones with the formulas. Otherwise I think you'd need to think about using a VBA script here instead, if you're interested.
[image]

Comment: Thank you Brendan. H for your response.  I appreciate you taking the time.